# Having an image in a qt window without having the image file itself as source

Tags: c++, image, qt

I have a window in Qt with an image (logo). For this small program to function the image file (png or jpeg) must be accessed from the exe-file. I wish to have the image saved somewhere as an array or else in some other format like cpp or h or else. Is this with Qt possible?

Comment: You might want to [use resources](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) to store your image

Comment: You could also draw the image at runtime if it is not extremely complex.

Comment: @MarcoA. Write a small answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @scopchanov I don't want to learn how to draw images but in a very broad sense yours is still a valid answer. So is to create T-1000 so he can then solve my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt Icon embedded in Executeable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681159/qt-icon-embedded-in-executeable)

Comment: @prometeu, given the question you asked, to store the painting operations in a `*.cpp` file is a completely valid answer, the same as having the image stored in array in `*.cpp` as raw data and draw it at runtime with QPainter on a QPixmap. By the way, I use those both approaches myself in a real working application. Which one is more suitable depends on the specific needs. If you do not have specific needs, however, then  I do not see how your question is different than this one: [Qt Icon embedded in Executeable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1681159/5366641).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this would be [using the Qt resources system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html).

You basically specify the resources to embed in a `.qrc` file and you can afterwards use them by providing the resource path

```
cutAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/cut.png"), tr("Cu&t"), this);
```